# Determine a and b in a polynomial long division so that the result is a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

I'm stuck with this, I've been trying factoring, rooting and I just don't understand what to do.

Determine a&b so that the result of the long division is polynomial
$$
\frac{x^3+ax^2+bx-4a}{x^2-2x-3}$$

Comment: `I've been trying factoring` What did you get for the denominator?

Comment: Basic stuff $(x+1)(x-3)$

Comment: Good, that's all you need. Next step, when does $\,x+1\,$ divide the numerator?

Comment: Aaand again I'm baffled. $ x^2-2x+1? $ It's been nearly twenty years since the last time I tried to solve these :)...

Comment: @JukkaSäily If you forgot the [polynomial remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem), then just write down the long division $\,p(x)=(x+1)(x-3)q(x)+r(x)\,$ with $r(x)\equiv0$, then set $x=-1, 3$ and you get a couple of equations in $a,b$ to solve.

Comment: Still not getting it. I think I'll get back to the very basics to refresh my memory and try again later. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JukkaSäily Lookup [polynomial long division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division), which is where the form in my previous comment comes from. Then substitute $x=-1$, which causes the RHS to vanish and leaves $p(-1)=-1+a-b-4a=0$. Repeat for $x=3$. Solve the two linear equations for $a,b$.

Answer (score 0):

@dxiv provided the answer. So take the following as a step-by-step elaboration, and I don't know... Upvote one of @dxiv's answers, or whatever...

What he/she is saying is that the polynomial remainder theorem states that the remainder of the division of a polynomial $p(x)$ by a linear form $x-n$ is equal to $p(n),$ i.e. the polynomial evaluated at $n:$

$$\frac{p(x)}{x-n} =q(x) + \frac{p(n)}{x-n}.$$

In here, $q(x)$ is the quotient polynomial (the answer of the division when the remainder is zero). This is the case in your problem: *the result of the long division is a polynomial*.

The expression above can be re-formulated as

$$p(x)=(x-n)\;q(x)\;+\;p(n).$$

We know that we can decompose the expression in your original question as:

$$\frac{x^3+ax^2+bx-4a}{x^2-2x-3}=\frac{x^3+ax^2+bx-4a}{(x+1)(x-3)}$$

Since the remainder is zero, i.e. $p(n)=0$, you can arrive in a couple of steps to

$$x^3+ax^2+bx-4a=(x+1)(x-3) \;q'(x)\tag 1$$

We don't know what $q(x)$ is right away, but it doesn't matter, because we know that when $x=-1,$ the expression on the RHS will be zero, and if we calculate the LHS of Eq. 1, we arrive at @dxiv equation under comments:

$$p(-1)=-1+a-b-4a=0$$

and the parallel equation for $x=3:$

$$p(3)= 27 +9a+3b -4a=0$$

Now we have a system with two unknowns and two equations.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If you use long division,
$$\frac{x^3+ax^2+bx-4a}{x^2-2x-3}=x+a+2+\frac{x (2 a+b+7)-a+6}{x^2-2x-3}$$ Then $a-6=0$ and $2a+b+7=0$ then $a$ and $b$.